# Output in div, prints objects in array, but first answer is "Undefined". - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm very new to this, and I was hoping to get some clarity in this: 
Whenever I run this code (PS: boardGames, is an array in a separate doc)
 It seems to work, but the first answer is always "undefined". Why is that? and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

```
var message;
var games;
var search;
var i;


function print(message) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}


function gamestoPlay( games ) {
  var topGames = '<h3> Game: ' + boardGames[i].name +'</h3>';
  topGames += '<p> Minimum Players: ' + boardGames[i].idealMinPlayers     + '</p>';
  topGames += '<p> Maximum Players: ' + boardGames[i].idealMaxPlayers     + '</p>';
  return topGames
}

search = parseInt(prompt('How many people are coming?'));

for (i = 0; i < boardGames.length; i += 1) {
  games = i;
  if ( search >= boardGames[i].idealMinPlayers && search <= boardGames[i].idealMaxPlayers) {
    message += gamestoPlay();
    print(message);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you define your boardGames array starting at [1] instead of [0]? Also try initializing message to an empty string ('').

Comment: Sounds like your code is running before the DOM is ready

Comment: initializing the message with an empty string did it! Thank you!!

Comment: @LeoMedina You might not be able to do this yet, but the good way of saying 'Thank You' here on SO is to accept the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't initialize `message`.

When you do

```
message += gamesToPlay();
```

it first has to convert `message` to a string so it can concatenate to it. Since you didn't initialize `message`, its value is `undefined`, and when this is converted to a string it becomes `"undefined"`, and then the result of `gamesToPlay()` is concatenated to that.

Change the initialization to:

```
var message = "";
```